# Mongodb Vm.max_map_count is too low in replicaset

Tags: linux, mongodb, replicaset

I have deployed mongodb to K8s with bitnami helm charts, and it is running as replicaset. When I log into mongodb terminal on secondary I see notification: “vm.max_map_count is too low”.

When checking on container, I see:

> sysctl vm.max_map_count
>
> vm.max_map_count = 26214

Per documentation the setting should be
`vm.max_map_count value of 128000`

So why am I getting this warning? Or should I increase the vm_max_count?

Checked 'sysctl vm.max_map_count'